# Is there a way to get a variable form Angular to Spark in Zeppelin

Tags: angular, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I know that the reverse is possible, where you can pass Spark variables to Angular, using `z.angularBind`, but what I want is to pass variables from Angular to Spark. A use case here is that the user fills information in an Angular form and when presses a button, the Spark program runs, after getting values passed from Angular. So, another question here is can I also run the Spark paragraph directly from within Angular?

To summarize my problem, basically on a button click, the Angular program would pass the variables to the Spark paragraph and also run that paragraph (I want an Angular version of `z.run`). Is that kind of a thing possible in Zeppelin?

Comment: Did you ever get to pass values from Angular -> spark? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z.angularBind is your friend for this.  See the documentation page here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/displaysystem/front-end-angular.html#run-paragraph

Answer (score 0):

```
%angular
<input type="text" ng-model="aaa" id="aaa" value= />
<button ng-click="z.angularBind('myvar','aaa','paragraph_xxx')">
```

paragraph_xxx:

```
%spark
val a = z.angular("myvar")
println(a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).